# Cakephp Session issue with chrome and firefox

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to use common session across two sub-domains using cakePHP. On my local setup its working fine in all the browsers but on server its working only in IE.

Following is the code i use in core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'PHPSESSID',
    'timeout' => 20000, // 1 hour
    'ini' => array(
    'session.cookie_domain' => '.dummy.com.au',
    'session.gc_maxlifetime' => 36000 // 1 hour
    )
));
```

I have set security level to low

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

But its still not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem in maintaining session between two different domains on a website done in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292897/problem-in-maintaining-session-between-two-different-domains-on-a-website-done-i)

Comment: Issue is with different browsers, code is working fine with IE and Safari but not working with IE, Opera and chrome.

Comment: Can you give us the result of ini_get('session.cookie_domain')?

Comment: its coming as .dummy.com.au